# Why does the mobile view of my website show a 404 Error?

Tags: html, web, http-status-code-404, cpanel, web-hosting

I am developing an html,css, javascript static site. I am using a plugin called AOS for on-scroll animation effects. I am also using bootstrap which I installed using npm.

Now when I run and test my files on localhost, everything is working flawlessly. Site loads on both the desktop as well as the mobile view. When I upload the site to cPanel, the desktop is working as it should but the mobile site is throwing a 404 error.
Here is the site link : https://hsit.ae

I have no clue what is the main issue. The server is throwing a response but not finding the right file.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look in your website, the problem occurs only when you have some source of mobile detection. if you resize your window to mobile width, it still operates the same.

My guess would be some JS code listening to "resize" event and then performing some error. or - some HTACCESS rules that try to look for a mobile version. Check that with your hosting provider.

Comment: Can I delete .htaccess file altogether ? I also believe that it is the main cause of this error ?

Comment: Back it up before and try to delete it, yes